# Сформировать массив массивов из выбранных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Делаю фильтрацию. Для отправки на сервер, необходимо заполнить массив, как ключ - значение, выбранными чекбоксами. Ключ - идентификатор атрибута, значение - одно из множеств значений атрибута. Пока то, что есть работает не так, как надо - выбирается только одно значение из одного ключа, нужно чтобы заносилось то, на чем стоит галочка. Только начинаю знакомство с `frontend` фрэймворками, `js`. Как я понимаю, то надо пушить массив в массив, но как это делается в `js` в связке c `Vue` понять не могу. Пытался байндить `value` инпута таким образом `:value="[id, value]"`, но на сервер приходит строка, можно запарсить, но... такой подход не устраивает. Вызов метода из `value` опять же работает в данном случае так, что выбирается только последние значение атрибута. Пока стоит событие на клик, но выбирается только одно значение, при выборе другого происходит его перезапись.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="get">

            <div v-for="attribute in attributes" >
                <div>
                    {{attribute.title}}
                    <div v-for="product in attribute.products">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" v-model="checked" value="1" @click.prevent="getFilter(attribute.id, product.pivot.value_id)"> {{ product.pivot.value_id }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

           {{checked}}

            <button type="submit">Фильтровать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                attributes: [],
                checked: {}
            }
        },

        methods:{
            getFilter(key, value){
                this.checked = Object.assign({}, this.checked, {[key]:value});
                console.log(this.checked);
            },
            fetch(){
                axios.get(`/getAttributes`,{
                    params:{
                        filter: this.checked
                    }
                })
                    .then(response=>{
                        this.attributes = response.data;
                    })
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.fetch();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Вам что сложно нормально код поставить?

Comment: Вот сейчас когда ваш код нормально видно, запустите его и посмотрите ошибку!

Comment: @Alt_F4,что-то я не догоняю, сборщик собирает все без ошибок))